# Programmatically change path for EF Core database in console project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core, to manage a SQLite database file, in a console project.

When I create a database, the file is created in the bin folder, so basically `MyProjectName\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\FooDatabase.sqlite`.

I want to change this.

I tried setting `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory` and `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath`. Nothing works.

How do I programmatically set the directory that the database should be created in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` 2.0 (not yet released), `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()` will do the trick.

Until then I suggest using an absolute path in your connection string:

```cs
var builder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder(relativeConnectionString);
bilder.DataSource = Path.Combine(dataDirectory, bilder.DataSource);
var absoluteConnectionString = builder.ToString();
```

If you *really* want to fiddle with the internal mechanics, you can, but I wouldn't recommend it:

```cs
// .NET Framework
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", myDataDirectory);

// .NET Core
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ADONET_DATA_DIR", myDataDirectory);
```

Comment: I guess second one won't work in .NET Core as no more AppDomain. But first would, but won't work with the ASP.NET DI container. Hope the 2.0 release drops soon.

Comment: @grokky I've updated my answer with what you shouldn't do on .NET Core. ;-)

Comment: Verified Directory.SetCurrentDirectory() works with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 5.0.  Thanks bricelam!