# Use the same EF database path in EF Core 1.1 and 2.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

My EF Core 1.1 and ASP.NET Core 1.1 app was looking for its SQLite database in `MySolution/MyProject/bin/[Debug|Release]/netcoreapp1.1/MyDatabase.db` (which I think was the default). My migrations created/migrated the database in that path, and everything worked.

I'm trying to upgrade to netcoreapp2.0, and my migrations still write to that directory. But at runtime, the app looks for the database in `MySolution/MyProject/` rather than the bin path. So of course it fails.

How do I get back the behavior from before?

Comment: show some code, it'll be helpful

Comment: @tchelidze What code? I never specified the path anywhere. So I expected the upgrade to 2,0 to behave in the same way,

Comment: "MyDatabase.db" name is not built into `asp.net core` you'll have specified it somewhere.

Comment: @tchelidze Yeah that's done in the `appsettings.json`, which has `"ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": "Filename=MyDatabase.db" }`, though I didn't change anything in there either :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a breaking change in EF Core 2.0 (issue [#7588](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7588)). You should move the database file into your project and specify **Copy to Output Directory**.

Comment: Thanks Brice! What do you think of my solution below? It works for me (though I haven't test in production), but are there any gotchas with it that make your recommendation better/safer? For example is it safe to use `AppContext.BaseDirectory` or should I use `IHostingEnvironment` or something like that?

Comment: On second thought.... The app is looking for the db in the app directory (location of `appsettings.json` file). My problem is that the db is already located in the bin/output directory, but the app is not looking in there...

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this, thanks to advice from @bricelam for a [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42561252/7059613):

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
  options => {
    var builder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    builder.DataSource = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, builder.DataSource);
    options.UseSqlite(builder.ToString());
  },
  ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

I tested this in development, but I'm not sure if it works in production, or if `AppContext.BaseDirectory` is safe to use (instead of `IHostingEnvironment` or something like that).